# Como carregar os dados do banco de dados para um jtable

Tags: java, jtable, padrão-dao, tablemodel

Na hora da execução aparece a mensagem de erro desse trecho e não estou conseguindo achar o erro. Sei que a conexão com o banco está certa porque tenho outras classes no mesmo programa fazendo a conexão sem erro algum.

```
private void carregarGrade(){
        try{
            FornecedorDAO fornecedorDAO = new FornecedorDAO();
            FornecedorTableModel ftm = (FornecedorTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
            ftm.SetDados(fornecedorDAO.listarTodos());
        }catch(Exception ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Erro ao carregar tabela"+ex.getMessage(), "Erro", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Na parte visual do BuscaFornecedor(), em propriedades no campo model do jTable, defina propriedade usando codigo personalizado: jTable.setModel(new FornecedorTableModel());